# Naming convention and image size(pixel) in iphone

Tags: ios, image, size, naming-conventions

what is naming convention and image size(in pixel) in iPhone?

1. iphone 4/4s
2. iphone 5
3. iphone 5s
4. iphone 6
5. iphone 6 plus
6. ipad
7. ipad retina.

Comment: for splash and other image.

Comment: "other image" what other image?, my apps typically have around 50 - 100 images. You'll need to be much more specific. Re splash image, have you even bothered to google / try to find this yourself? its very easy to find: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW1